# php create class with no variables to pass in function

Tags: php, class

Lets say I have a class with a function in it:

classes.php

```
 class Foobar{
        function writeWord($word){
               return $word;
        }
 }
```

On the page that i call this class i need to initialize the class, then call it later.

php2.php

```
require_once('classes.php');
$something = new Foobar();

 echo $something->writeWord('Dog');
```

The problem here is that php comes back and says Foobar is missing arguments on line 1. how can I solve this?

Comment: are both codes on same php file ?

Comment: include file 1 ...   http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php

Comment: no they are seperate files.

Comment: Presumably, this is not your real code.  In your real code, is your function name the same as your class name?  If so, then your function will run on instantiation of the class - which has no parameter passed into it.

Comment: yes. That was the problem @ChrisMaggs.  thank you for pointing that out.

Comment: PHP 4 style constructors will be finally [deprecated in PHP 7](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/php-7.0.0beta1/UPGRADING#L593-L594). Also, as of PHP 5.3.3, these "constructors" are ignored [if the class is namespaced](http://php.net/__construct).